# How does mysql count in used connections?

Tags: mysql

As per my question, I would like to ask how does mysql count `used connections`. Is it by browser trying to connect to the server? Computer? IP Address?

Yesterday, our client's server got an error message Cant Connect to database. When we try to login to mysql, it gave an error Too many connections. We had to restart mysqld. This started when we added a cron job to run a PHP script at 2 AM in the morning. The PHP script's function is to check a table and update a value. The start and end of the function has properly opened and closed the DB connection.

We wish to know so that we can come out with a countermeasure.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/too-many-connections.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-interfaces.html - it is the sum of all of socket connections and tcp / ip connections to the MySQL server. (unless your database is exposed to the internet) on a web server that is every script / web app that connects to the database - unless you’re using connection poling that scales with the number site visitors you get and the number of applications that run

Answer (score 0):

The commandline "mysql" counts when it is running.  If you have multiple instances running, then each counts.

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Max_used_connections';` If that is the same as `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_connections';`, then you hit the limit.

Web servers spawn off threads (or processes) (running PHP, Java, etc). to handle multiple users.  In some installations, the limit that the webserver has is bigger than MySQL's `max_connections` setting.  This can lead to "too many connections".

I recommend lowering the webserver's limit of children as the 'better' setting to change.

The information does not care whether the connections are "localhost" (socket) or TCP/IP.  Yes, connection pooling adds confusion, without necessarily adding any benefit.